# When will be the next SharePoint version coming?

Tags: feature, feature-upgrade, 2013

I can't wait for a better version of SharePoint. I heard that the next version is SharePoint 2012 but now we have reach year 2012 but yet not receive any news on the beta version or even alpha version of the SharePoint.

Anyone have any ideas when it will be coming out and what are some great features that it have?

Comment: I am making this a Community Wiki because of the necessarily speculative nature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please visit [this blog from Joel Oleson](http://www.sharepointjoel.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=509) where he describes about SharePoint 15 and Office 15 Wave of Products !!!

You can also check out for the [Technical Preview Program](http://blogs.office.com/b/office-exec/archive/2012/01/30/quot-office-15-quot-begins-technical-preview.aspx) from Office

Answer (score 4):

Nobody knows. Well, nobody who is talking knows. However, on January 30 Microsoft has released Office 15 and SharePoint 15 into ‘Technical Preview’, a program that allows select users to try out the new software and provide feedback to Microsoft.

You can download both document sets at http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=28768

and

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeinteroperability/archive/2012/01/30/office-15-technical-preview-open-specification-update.aspx

There’s also a single-document version of the protocol documentation available at

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=25255

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint 2013 Preview was released yesterday.